# group_by and apply a rolling regression based on window using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 6,618 x 8
    Open  High   Low Close   Volumn Adjusted stock dates     
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> <date>    
 1  232.  237.  230.  233. 15470700     233. 1     2007-01-03
 2  234.  241.  233.  241. 15834200     241. 1     2007-01-04
 3  240.  243.  238.  243. 13795600     243. 1     2007-01-05
 4  243.  244.  240.  241.  9544400     241. 1     2007-01-08
```

I would like to calculate a 30 day rolling regression. What I have currently is:

```
df %>%
  group_by(stock) %>% 
  rollapply(
    width = 30,
    FUN = function(x){
      LinearModel = lm(formula = Close ~ date, data = as.data.frame(x))
      return(LinearModel$coef)
    })
```

This doesn't work, but I would like to have new columns in the `df` where I have the 30 day slopes and intercepts. I have tried wrapping the above function into a `mutate` without luck. I am trying to do this for each group in the `stock` column.

Data:

```
library(quantmod)
library(dplyr)
library(stats)
getSymbols(c("GOOG", "MSFT"), from = "2010-01-01", to = "2010-06-01")

names_for_column <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volumn", "Adjusted")
colnames(GOOG) <- names_for_column
colnames(MSFT) <- names_for_column

df <- bind_rows(data.frame(GOOG), data.frame(MSFT), .id = "stock") %>% 
  mutate(dates = c(time(GOOG), time(MSFT))) %>% 
  tibble()
```

Expected output:

```
    Open  High   Low Close   Volumn Adjusted stock dates          intercept   slope
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> <date>          
 1  232.  237.  230.  233. 15470700     233. 1     2007-01-03        NA (for 30 obs)
...
 30  234.  241.  233.  241. 15834200     241. 1     2007-01-04      -0.324     0.284
```

EDIT:

I would like the output to be similar to a rolling version of:

```
df %>%
  filter(stock == 1) %>%
  condense(LinearModel = lm(Close ~ dates, data = .)) %>%
  tidy(LinearModel) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = term, values_from = estimate:p.value)
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 8
  `estimate_(Inte… estimate_dates `std.error_(Int… std.error_dates `statistic_(Int…
             <dbl>          <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>
1           -3123.          0.231             25.5         0.00159            -123.
# … with 3 more variables: statistic_dates <dbl>, `p.value_(Intercept)` <dbl>,
#   p.value_dates <dbl>
```

So I am hoping to bind this to the original data.

When I run:

```
df %>%
  filter(stock == 1) %>%
  condense(out = lm(Close ~ dates, data =.) %>% 
             tidy)
```

I get:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
# Rowwise: 
  out             
  <list>          
1 <tibble [2 × 5]>
```

Adding `unnest()`

```
df %>%
  filter(stock == 1) %>%
  condense(out = lm(Close ~ dates, data =.) %>% 
             tidy) %>% 
  unnest(out)
```

I get the same result (without the `pivot_wider` part) as before:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  term         estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 (Intercept) -3123.     25.5         -123.       0
2 dates           0.231   0.00159      145.       0
```

I want to flatten this data and link it up to the corresponding dates in the original data (with the first 30 rows containing NA). I am mostly interested in the values `-3123` and `0.231` from the `estimate` column.

#

EDIT -

Comment: please check this example [runner-example](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/articles/runner_examples.html#weeks-regression)
This might solve your problem. You can execute runner in `group_by/mutate`

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach/article, just thinking how I can apply it to my problem.

Comment: rollapply works column by column separately unless you use the argument `by.column=FALSE` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `group_split` and `map` over the `list` elements and then apply the `rollapply`

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- df %>% 
        group_split(stock) %>%
        map(~ rollapply(.x,
           width = 30,
           FUN =  function(dat) {
           LinearModel = lm(formula = Close ~ dates,  as.data.frame(dat))
           LinearModel$coef
           }, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA_real_,  align = "right"))


length(out)
#[1] 2
```

---

If we want to update the original dataset with more columns

```
out <-  df %>% 
       group_split(stock) %>%
       map_dfr(~ {
           subdat <- .x
           rollapply(subdat,
           width = 30,
           FUN =  function(dat) {
           LinearModel = lm(formula = Close ~ dates,  as.data.frame(dat))
           LinearModel$coef
           }, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA_real_,  align = "right") %>% 
               as.data.frame %>%
               bind_cols(subdat, .)

           }

           )

ncol(out)
#[1] 38

ncol(df)
#[1] 8
```

---

In the devel version of `dplyr`, we can also do

```
out1 <- df %>% 
           group_by(stock) %>%
          condense(out =rollapply(cur_data(), width = 30,
           FUN = function(dat) lm(Close ~ dates, as.data.frame(dat))$coef,
           by.column = FALSE, fill = NA_real_, align = "right") %>% 
           as.data.frame %>%
           bind_cols(cur_data(), .))
out1
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Rowwise:  stock
#  stock out                  
#  <chr> <list>               
#1 1     <tibble [3,309 × 37]>
#2 2     <tibble [3,309 × 37]>
```

The `list` column can be `unnest`ed when it is required

```
out1 %>% 
    unnest(c(out)) %>%
    head(3)
# A tibble: 3 x 38
#  stock  Open  High   Low Close Volumn Adjusted dates      `(Intercept)` `dates2007-01-0…
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <date>             <dbl>            <dbl>
#1 1      232.  237.  230.  233. 1.55e7     233. 2007-01-03            NA               NA
#2 1      234.  241.  233.  241. 1.58e7     241. 2007-01-04            NA               NA
#3 1      240.  243.  238.  243. 1.38e7     243. 2007-01-05            NA               NA
# … with 28 more variables: `dates2007-01-05` <dbl>, `dates2007-01-08` <dbl>,
#   `dates2007-01-09` <dbl>, `dates2007-01-10` <dbl>, `dates2007-01-11` <dbl>,
#   `dates2007-01-12` <dbl>, `dates2007-01-16` <dbl>, `dates2007-01-17` <dbl>,
#   `dates2007-01-18` <dbl>, `dates2007-01-19` <dbl>, `dates2007-01-22` <dbl>,
#   `dates2007-01-23` <dbl>, `dates2007-01-24` <dbl>, `dates2007-01-25` <dbl>,
#   `dates2007-01-26` <dbl>, `dates2007-01-29` <dbl>, `dates2007-01-30` <dbl>,
#   `dates2007-01-31` <dbl>, `dates2007-02-01` <dbl>, `dates2007-02-02` <dbl>,
#   `dates2007-02-05` <dbl>, `dates2007-02-06` <dbl>, `dates2007-02-07` <dbl>,
#   `dates2007-02-08` <dbl>, `dates2007-02-09` <dbl>, `dates2007-02-12` <dbl>,
#   `dates2007-02-13` <dbl>, `dates2007-02-14` <dbl>
```

---

We can apply the `tidy` within the `condense`

```
library(broom)

out3 <-  df %>% 
   group_split(stock) %>%
   map_dfr(~ {
       subdat <- .x
       rollapply(subdat,
       width = 30,
       FUN =  function(dat) {
       LinearModel = lm(formula = Close ~ dates,  as.data.frame(dat))
       tidy(LinearModel)
       }, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA_real_,  align = "right") %>% 
           as.data.frame %>%
           bind_cols(subdat, .)

       }

       )



dim(out3)
#[1] 6618   13
names(out3)
# [1] "Open"      "High"      "Low"       "Close"     "Volumn"    "Adjusted"  "stock"    
# [8] "dates"     "term"      "estimate"  "std.error" "statistic" "p.value"
```

Comment: Thanks! sorry I have not been at the computer the last 30 mins. This is almost what I want but I would like for each date rolling a single line from `df %>% 
  filter(stock == 1) %>%
  condense(LinearModel = lm(Close ~ dates, data = .)) %>% 
  tidy(LinearModel) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = term, values_from = estimate:p.value)` so I will have a rolling `estimate` , `std.error`, `statistic`, `p.value` etc.

Comment: @user113156 the `tidy` would be inside the `condense` i.e.  `condense(out = lm(Close ~ dates, data =.) %>% tidy)`

Comment: oh I see, thanks. How can I apply something similar but for each group over a rolling window. I will add the expected output I have in mind to the original post.

Comment: @user113156 I updated. the post.  can you please check.  My system is getting slower by running this multiple times.  sorry

Comment: Yes, it is a little slow for me, perhaps I will increase the window size or reduce the data size. Your final output gives me almost what I was after. I think you have given me enough ideas so I can try and solve it from here.

Comment: @user113156 it is taking some time to run

Comment: `out1` gives me 2 data frames but I am not sure where the columns come from i.e. I have columns `dates2007-01-04`, `dates2007-01-05`, `dates2007-01-08` etc. I was expecting a column for the `estimate` - `(Intercept)` and another column from the `estimate`- `dates` (or row 1 and row 2 from the `estimate` column.

Comment: It is slow for me also. The `df` is unnecessarily large (running daily regressions from 2007 - 2020). I changed the `getSymbols(c("GOOG", "MSFT"), from = "2010-01-01", to = "2010-06-01")` and re-ran my above `data` code and now have 204 observations which is more manageable.

Comment: Looking at your `out3` I get `(Intercept)` then `dates2010-01-05` ... (30 dates) ...  `dates2010-02-16` then another `(Intercept)` but if it is a rolling regression should I get an intercept each day after 30 days (along with a slope).

Comment: @user113156 I showed the column names.  which are ` "estimate"  "std.error" "statistic" "p.value"`

Comment: @user113156. when you apply `tidy`, these are the columns you are gettiing as output (it is also the same in your post)

Comment: When I run `df %>%
  filter(stock == 1) %>%
  condense(LinearModel = lm(Close ~ dates, data = .)) %>%
  tidy(LinearModel)` I get a single value for `(Intercept)` and a single value for `dates`). That is based on the whole sample period. splitting the sample period up into a rolling window of 30 should give me these two values each day after 30 days, right?

Comment: @user113156 if you check the priint output  of `tidy` `df %>% group_by(stock) %>% condense(out = rollapply(cur_data(), width = 30, FUN = function(dat) lm(Close ~ dates, as.data.frame(dat))   %>% {print(head(tidy(.), 3)); tidy(.)},   by.column = FALSE, fill = NA_real_, align = "right")) -> out4` isn't it doing this on each loop

Comment: I went back to this problem and "solved" it in a different way using lists. I made an edit `EDIT - new method:`. I think the rolling method you suggest is a better way but I cannot seem to get the data in the final form. If you have any ideas based on the new edit let me know. If not I will keep trying. Thanks again!

Comment: sure, will look into it

Comment: Okay I think I have something: I apply the following `rollify` from the `tibbletime` package `library(tibbletime)

rolling_lm <- rollify(.f = function(Close, dates){
  lm(Close ~ dates)$coef
}, window = 30, unlist = FALSE)

x <- df %>% 
  filter(stock == 1) %>% 
  mutate(roll_lm = rolling_lm(Close, dates))`  which gives me a nice data frame. Now I want to extract from `roll_lm` (into two columns) the "Intercept" and the "dates" value from the nested lists. Then I think this solves my issue.

Comment: let me install that package

Comment: @user113156 give me some time, my laptop shutdown suddenly and had to make some changes

Comment: I have solved it, thanks though. The issue was that `date` was a character so it was creating new variables based on the `date`. I wanted a single slope value but I was getting slopes for each of the dates. Adding `mutate(date = as.Date(date))` to my final EDIT gives me a single `intercept` and a single `slope`.